# Decoding a thing or a list of things in json

Tags: json, elm

I'm trying to parse JSON-LD, and one of the possible constructs is

```
"John" : { 
  "type": "person",
  "friend": [ "Bob", "Jane" ],
}
```

I would like to decode into records of type

```
type alias Triple = 
  { subject: String, predicate: String, object: String }
```

so the example above becomes:

```
Triple "John" "type" "person"
Triple "John" "friend" "Bob"
Triple "John" "friend" "Jane"
```

But "friend" in the JSON object could also be just a string:

```
"friend": "Mary"
```

in which case the corresponding triple would be

```
Triple "John" "friend" "Mary"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you'll need a way to list all key/value pairs from a JSON object. Elm offers the [`Json.Decode.keyValuePairs`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#keyValuePairs) function for this purpose. It gives you a list of key names which you'll use for the `predicate` field, but you'll also have to describe a decoder for it to use for the values.

Since your values are either a string or a list of strings, you can use [`Json.Decode.oneOf`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#oneOf) to help. In this example, we'll just convert a string to a singleton list (e.g. `"foo"` becomes `["foo"]`), just because it makes it easier to map over later.

```elm
stringListOrSingletonDecoder : Decoder (List String)
stringListOrSingletonDecoder =
    JD.oneOf
        [ JD.string |> JD.map (\s -> [ s ])
        , JD.list JD.string
        ]
```

Since the output of `keyValuePairs` will be a list of `(String, List String)` values, we'll need a way to flatten those into a `List (String, String)` value. We can define that function like this:

```elm
flattenSnd : ( a, List b ) -> List ( a, b )
flattenSnd ( key, vals ) =
    List.map (\val -> ( key, val )) vals
```

Now you can use these two functions to split up an object into a triple. This accepts a string argument which is the key to look up in your calling function (e.g. we need to look up the wrapping `"John"` key).

```elm
itemDecoder : String -> Decoder (List Triple)
itemDecoder key =
    JD.field key (JD.keyValuePairs stringListOrSingletonDecoder)
        |> JD.map
            (List.map flattenSnd
                >> List.concat
                >> List.map (\( a, b ) -> Triple key a b)
            )
```

[See a working example here on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/p7BCpkKSkqa1).

*Note that the order of keys may not match how you listed them in the input JSON, but that is just how JSON works. It's a lookup table, not an ordered list*

Comment: `JD.map (\s -> [ s ])` That's what I was missing! Thanks